# Azure Copy Blob REST API is throwing AuthenticationFailed with SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to call Azure Copy Blob API from postman. I have passed below headers and hit the request but I am getting "AuthenticationFailed" error.

I am sure, I might have given wrong header values or missed some required headers. Can some please help me what am I missing.

Here is the request:

Method: PUT
URL: https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/SAMPLE_FILE.CSV

Headers:

Authorization = **SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE:?sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupitfx&se=2023-05-30T06:52:46Z&st=2022-05-31T22:52:46Z&spr=https,http&sig=lP1fdHkWabckHlMFOrUsAWyVu6zxxJwNX4l%2B6a0WAmE%3D**

x-ms-version = **2015-04-05**

x-ms-copy-source = **https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/SAMPLE_FILE.CSV
x-ms-date = 2022-06-13T18:51:28.5001104Z**

Response Received:

Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:aa820193-601e-0037-5959-7f7a5b000000

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using incorrect authorization header.

When you use SAS token, you would need to use SAS URL as the base URL for your copy operation and do not include authorization header as SAS token already contains the authorization information.

Do try with the following PUT URL and you will not get the authorization failed error (assuming your SAS token is valid):

```
Method: PUT URL:
https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/SAMPLE_FILE.CSV?sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupitfx&se=2023-05-30T06:52:46Z&st=2022-05-31T22:52:46Z&spr=https,http&sig=lP1fdHkWabckHlMFOrUsAWyVu6zxxJwNX4l%2B6a0WAmE%3D
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav...It worked fine after making suggested change